# PHP error on login page

Tags: php, authentication, system

A tried to create a login system and was stoped by an error which I can't solve !

> Undefined index: user_name in C:\xamppp\htdocs\eatswrong\member.php on line 4

here is the login code !

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($username&&$password) {

$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','')
        or die('An error occured while conneting  !');
mysql_select_db('blogpers') or die('Eroare la conectarea cu baza de date !');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows !=0) {

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

        $dbusername = $rows['username'];
        $dbpassword = $rows['password'];

    }

    if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword) {
        echo "You're in ! <a href='member.php'>Click</a> here to enter the membership              page ! ";
        $_SESSION['user_name']=$username;
    } else{
        echo 'Incorrect password!';
    }

} else {
    die("That user doesn't exist !");
}

      } else {
 echo 'Please enter username and password !';
}
  ?>
```

And here is the membership page code :

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if($_SESSION['user_name']) {
      echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['user_name']."!"; 
   echo "<a href='logout.php'>Log OUT</a>";
   } else {
  echo "To acces this page please log in !";
   }

    ?>
```

Comment: The most likely cause could be that your form elements are not named or there's a typo.

Comment: when i'm logged I have not this error !

Comment: undefined index is not an error, it is a notice. and just check if it exists using (isset, array_key_exists) depends on your logic, and you need to know that your code is open for all security problems

Comment: Then you may need to change `$username = $_POST['username'];` to `$username = $_POST['username'] = $_SESSION['user_name'];` then change your conditional statement to `if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_name'])){`

Comment: $_SESSION['user_name'] only gets set if a successful login occurs, but your "welcome" code tries to access it unconditionally, whether a login occured or not.

Comment: [3,600+](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Undefined+index+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your warning is in  membership page in this line:

```
if($_SESSION['user_name']) {
```

should be:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) {
```

you need to check if user_name is set in the session or not.It should solve your this issue.

Comment: @Denis.: did you try this?

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution to your problem

You get the notification (which won't stop the script from running or working in most cases) because you're checking for index `'user_name'` inside `$_SESSION`, but the index is not set.

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['user_name']) { // <-- Checking here, but there's nothing setting it above it. session_start(); does not set it
```

Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to see if it's set instead. You probably also want to check that it's not empty using [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) or some other method that might even check that the username is valid.

#### About your use of mysql_*

Another thing to note is that you're using deprecated MySQL API, which the `mysql_*` functions are. See [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for an up-to-date, and more secure, choice.

#### Last but certainly not least

You're not sanitizing the input from the user - at all. If someone were to send their [an SQL query (slightly modified) as their username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), your script would run it and bad stuff could happen. If you're not going to switch to a more secure API, at least use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should not fetch all info about user.
It should be like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password ='$password' ");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows == 1) {
```

So, in the future:

-dont use mysql_* functions, it is deprecated  and will be remove.Read about PDO

-read about functions empty() and isset().

Good luck:)